# Attribute never updates between requests to a FlaskView

Tags: python, class, rest, methods, flask

I've a class like this:

```py
class  ma_class(FlaskView):
  route_base = '/'

  state = False

  @route('/load')
  def load(self):
      self.state = True
      return 'load : ok'

  @route('/stuff')
  def do_something(self)
    if not self.state:
        return 'you must invoke load method'
```

When I send a request to `url/load` I get `Load : ok` in the response.

But after, when I send a request to `url/stuff` I get `you must invoke load method`.

`self.state` hasn't changed, and I have no idea why.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Short and rather simplified answer would be "because http is stateless".

Comment: Flask creates a new instance of the view for every request. **This is by design**.

Comment: ah ok, so what could be the solution ? Pass trough a file ?

Comment: Depends on your application. Most of the time using sessions: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http` is stateless. This means that one request does not know anything about the second request and so on, unless you tell it in some way. If you are using flask, you can use "session" to achieve that. Sessions are a way to save information acorss multiple requests (e.g login).

```
from flask import session

class  ma_class(FlaskView):
  route_base = '/'


@route('/load')
def load(self):

  session['state'] = True
  return 'load : ok'

@route('/stuff')
def do_something(self)
   if 'state' not in session:
       return 'you must invoke load method'
```